# Unsigned Char Template Value Overflow

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I'm using the following template to encode unsigned char values:

```
template <unsigned char val>
struct Cell {
    enum { value = val };

    using add = Cell<val + 1>;
    using sub = Cell<val - 1>;
};
```

I expected `sub` to behave like a standard `unsigned char` variable regarding overflow:

```
unsigned char x = 0;
x - 1; // 255
```

But instead I get a compiler error in Clang:

```
using cell = Cell<0>;
cell::sub::value; // Error here.


Non-type template argument evaluates to -1, which cannot be narrowed to type 'unsigned char'
```

Is overflow handled differently in template contexts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`val - 1` is an `int` on your platform, on account of the usual arithmetic conversions. There is no sensible meaning for a template parameter of type `unsigned char` to be given an `int` argument.

Simply make sure that your template argument has the desired type:

```
using sub = Cell<static_cast<unsigned char>(val - 1U)>;
//               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       ^^
```

(Using an `unsigned int` literal means that the usual conversions produce an `unsigned int`, which has well-defined narrowing semantics.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction and providing a solution. Here is an article explaining c++ integral promotion in a bit more detail: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast#Integral_promotion

Comment: @KerrekSB Ah, right. `unsigned int` is also possible.

Comment: *"There is no sensible meaning for a template parameter of type unsigned char to be given an int argument."* I think it is possible, it just may not be a narrowing conversion. I.e., `val - 1` can be converted to an `unsigned char` as long as `val > 0`.

Comment: @dyp: yes, every problem can be solved by forbidding all but a solvable subset of the problem. Assume I'm saying "in general" unless otherwise stated :-S

Comment: Well I'm referring to 5.19/3 "A converted constant expression of
type `T` is an expression, implicitly converted to a prvalue of type `T`, where the converted expression is a core constant expression and the implicit conversion sequence contains only [list of some conversions] other than narrowing conversions." which is used by [temp.arg.nontype]/5 to specify the conversions allowed for template non-type arguments.

Comment: I think the `static_cast` is not required for `-`, only for `+` (when using `1U`, there's no problem with negative values). But making it asymmetric for `+` and `-` might be strange..